# Is there a name for the parts that are connected by a conjunction?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

For example, the parts of a sentence that a preposition operates on are called "prepositional objects". I was wondering if there's a name for the parts that are connected by a conjunction? E.g. in "apples and oranges", would we say "apple" and "orange" are the *objects* of "and"?

Comment: Er, *coordinates*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are its *coordinands*; see http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Coordinand.

(That page also lists some alternatives, namely *term*, *member*, *coordinated unit*, *coordinate*, and *conjunct*.)

Comment: That is a difficult word to say. I tried four times, and it still sounds funny.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of that word but that's exactly what I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 3):

[*elements*](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm): when a coordinating conjunction is used to connect **all the elements** in a series, a comma is not used:

Presbyterians *and* Methodists *and* Baptists are the prevalent Protestant congregations in Oklahoma.

[*equivalent sentence elements*](http://www.writingcentre.uottawa.ca/hypergrammar/conjunct.html): Correlative conjunctions always appear in pairs -- you use them to link **equivalent sentence elements**.

[*elements*](http://www.towson.edu/ows/conjunctions.htm): A coordinating conjunction joining three or more words, phrases, or subordinate clauses creates a series and requires commas between **the elements**.

Comment: No: they're the elements of the series, not the elements of the conjunction.

Comment: @ruakh - I didn't say they were elements *of the conjunction.* I said they were *elements*. Which they are. Elements.

Comment: I know you didn't *mean* to say they were elements of the conjunction, but the question was "would we say 'apple' and 'orange' are the *objects* of 'and'?", and your answer was "*elements*". So you did say that.

Comment: Humph! You are exactly correct. My apolgies. I should have read the OP's question more carefully. Thank you. :)